# Enabling Photoshop CS5 Extended Features in Master Collection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5, photoshop-cs5

How do I enable Photoshop Extended features in CS5 Master Collection?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific way to enable it. Master Collection includes Photoshop Extended therefore each time you run Photoshop, you run it in Extended "mode".